# Customize highchart graphs with different labels

Tags: angular, highcharts, bar-chart, progress-bar

In my highchart graphs, multiple linear bar charts are displayed to show progress for different data sets. By showing data corresponding to each bar in these charts, I am trying to customize them. Here is how I would like the graph displayed.

[image]

It has been done successfully to create graphs with different types of data, but now I have to display the related data using the above format. I have altered the attributes to add them as the same. However, it did not reflect.

A working version of the graph code is provided below.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Athulya_Ratheesh/rb2m85av/74/)

Also graph data example :

```
const data= [{ name:”Apple”, Actual_Selling : 1220 , Estimated_selling : 2000},
{ name:”Orange”, Actual_Selling : 45 , Estimated_selling : 800},
{ name:”Pears”, Actual_Selling : 1220 , Estimated_selling : 300},
{ name:”Grape”, Actual_Selling : 456 , Estimated_selling : 56},
{ name:”Banana”, Actual_Selling : 55 , Estimated_selling : 800}]
```

Comment: Me too have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `xAxis.labels.formatter` which when `xAxis.labels.useHTML` is set to `true` allows you to use HTML there. Before that, however, you need to properly parse the data and pass it using categories.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5oteqmwa/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML